# Element.hidden variable portability

Tags: html, javascript

I'm writing a template page for a personal site I'm designing, and I'm going to be using drop-down DIV tags for the log-in form.

I'm also using Google Chrome as my primary testing, etc. browser, and noticed that all visible Elements appear to have a property called 'hidden' that holds a boolean value.

It works just like you'd expect, becoming hidden when set to True and visible when set to False.

```
document.getElementById("element").hidden = true;
document.getElementById("element").hidden = false;
```

Strangely enough, even Firefox 8.0.1 handles this in the same manner.

As my Google-fu hasn't been able to turn up any information on this, does anybody here know why this appears to be working, and how many other browsers support this?

I will add that this website I'm building is for my personal use, so cross-browser-compatibility is not intended, but would be a nice side-effect.

Comment: Are you talking about CSS 'visibility' - if so, that enjoys I would say almost 100% support.

Comment: No, this is strictly JavaScript stuff. I've added an example to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hidden` is a new global attribute introduced in HTML5. This means that browser support should be fairly good in modern browsers, though it will not be supported in IE8, and possibly IE9. As an aside, your use of the `hidden` attribute is probably incorrect.

> This `Boolean` attribute indicates that the element is not yet, or is no longer, *relevant*. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can't be used until the login process has been completed. The browser won't render such elements.

Your login form is not part of the page that is no longer relevant, but rather simply hidden as part of the presentation. You should therefore be using CSS for this instead. For more information, see:

- Relevant MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-hidden
- HTML5 specifications: http://developers.whatwg.org/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the same as doing:

```
<div hidden="true"></div>
```

However I would suggest you just do:

```
document.getElementById('question').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: How is this relevant to his question on browser compatibility? You also made a mistake there closing the `div` tag

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jaap It was PeeHaa of 2011 :D

Comment: @RahilWazir: It still shows up in the Low Quality Queue. And that comment is automatically generated when you flag to close.

Comment: @Jaap How does it not answer OP? OP asks why `document.getElementById("element").hidden = true;` works. I showed him/her what it renders. OP clearly states in the comments it was about the javascript stuff

Comment: It works because of HTML5 `hidden` attribute, as Yi Jiang said. Therefore your answer may be considered at best as a comment that offers an alternative technique to hide an element.

Comment: Last thing I am going to say about all this: Read the first two lines of my answer. Feel free to downvote + delvote if you people (i.e. the community) still feel it's not an answer though :-)